# MySQL Update Statement does not work in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a simple sql update statement for MySQL. When I run it alone, it works fine.

```
UPDATE 
temp_student 
INNER JOIN student 
ON temp_student.card = student.card 
SET studentid = student.id;
```

But when I put it in a stored procedure, none of the rows in the table is updated. Anyone can provide a clue? Thanks.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `eceintern2`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `copy_from_temp_student`$$

CREATE DEFINER = `root` @`localhost` PROCEDURE `copy_from_temp_student` () 
BEGIN
  UPDATE 
    temp_student 
    INNER JOIN student 
      ON temp_student.card = student.card 
      SET studentid = student.id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I don't know if that's the reason, but in the stand alone version, you are using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I tried both INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN. Does not help. Sorry that I forget to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to be no problem.

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `copy_from_temp_student`()
BEGIN
    UPDATE `temp_student` 
        INNER JOIN `student` ON `temp_student`.`card` = `student`.`card`
    SET `temp_student`.`studentid` = `student`.`id`;
END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8124/1)</kbd>